# How to put letter out of string? C language

Tags: c, string

```
void getAvailableLetters(char lettersGuessed[], char availableLetters[])
```

is function that I need to create. It must use strings.

- availableLetters are letters of alphabet
- lettersGuessed are letters inserted by user
- function is supposed to do this:

Available letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Gimme a letter: (let's guess 'm')
Available letters: abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyz //all without letter m
Gimme a letter: (let's hess 'b')
Available letters: acdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyz //all without letters m & b

Any algorythms, advices, codes or smth what would help me to do it would be great.

Comment: I you haven't done so yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: whatever language you are using, if lettersGuessed and availableLetters  are strings, there must be a replace method to get rid of the letter you need to remove from the alphabet.

Comment: @RobertoNovelo Are you sure that `C` has a string replace "method"? I seriously doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

Test this one out. The function `char_replace()` takes in the source string, the character to find and the string to replace the character (can be also one char). In your case, you pass `""` (empty value) for the char to be replaced with, because you want to remove it. But the parameter might come in handy, so I included it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *char_replace(char *, char, char *);

int main(void) {
    char input[4096] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char *signature = char_replace(input, 'a', "");
    printf("%s\n", input);

    return 0;
}

char *char_replace(char *str, char find, char *replace) {
    char *ret=str;
    char *wk, *s;
    // string duplication
    wk = s = strdup(str);

    while (*s != 0) {
        if (*s == find){
            while(*replace)
                *str++ = *replace++;
            ++s;
        } else
            *str++ = *s++;
    }
    *str = '\0';
    free(wk);
    // returning the result string
    return ret;
}
```

This approach is counting on the `input` array of chars (string) to have enough space with 4096 allocated to it.

Comment: this one is not working,     char *signature is unused value and char *replace is declared wrong

Comment: @Bobrys it is working (compile just with `gcc filename.c -o filename`. This is a very sticks and stones solution, but it should get you where you need to go. We're not free code-writing community. You're supposed to do the work, this is just a hint.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char    availableLetters[27]={"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"},lettersGuessed[2];

void getAvailableLetters(char lettersGuessed[], char availableLetters[])

{

int i,flag=0;

for(i=0;availableLetters[i]!='\0';i++)

{

if(availableLetters[i]==lettersGuessed[0])

{

flag=1;

for(;availableLetters[i]!='\0';i++)

{

availableLetters[i]=availableLetters[i+1];


}

}

if(flag==1)

{

availableLetters[i-1]='\0'; 

break;

}

}

}

input()

{

printf("Gimme a letter:");

scanf("%c",&lettersGuessed[0]);

fflush(stdin);  //deleting extra characters

lettersGuessed[1]='\0';

}

output()

{

printf("Available letters:");

puts(availableLetters);

}

main()

{

output();

input();

getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed,availableLetters);

output();

input();

getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed,availableLetters);

output();
}
```